# Apache stop redirecting to https:// from http://

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am using Apache with passenger for rails app, when i type http://localhost , it automatically rediects to https://localhost. How can i stop it

Thanks

Comment: By finding out what causes that redirect. You have to check 1. the configuration of your host for redirection rules and 2. any potantial `.htaccess` style files inside your documents folder. This task probably will be easier for you if you read a few things about how redirecting is done in an http server. Then you have a more clear idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: where to check 1)the configuration of my host for redirection rules, in /sites-available/000-default.conf , i did not write any code

Comment: If that is a "normal" installation of a package, then the configuration should be somewhere under `/etc/apache2` or `/etc/httpd` or similar. You are looking for something like `RewriteRule`...

Comment: Sorry dude, it was due to browser cache, which redirect me to https, Thanks dude for helping :)

Answer (score 3):

For disabling SSL without a command you can manually edit the SSLEngine directive in your ssl configuration file (usually in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf)
change:

```
SSLEngine on
```

to:

```
SSLEngine off
```

restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

from: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html

Comment: mine worked by adding SSLEngine off directive in the httpd.conf file